# How to record both audio, Where i have one music running and my microphone is in use?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, sound, pulseaudio, audacity

I have one music playing, and i have microphone open, already the microphone is used by other application.

In such case, how can i record that music and the microphone audio to a file? (if possible with command line).

**Follow up:**

```
$ rec new-file.wav

Input File     : 'default' (alsa)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:00:25.94 [00:00:00.00] Out:1.24M [      |      ]        Clip:0    ^C

$ sox −d new-file.wav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install audacity and select the record source to ALSA: default. This will record everything. Try experimenting with audacity, there are many useful settings.

Answer (score 0):

When music is playing, it will also be captured by your microphone if it is loud enough, so you can just record the microphone, or add the music later by editing